# sql Exception Invalid string or Buffer Length

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

i have started the java and just completed core java ...but i am not able to proceed further because of the sqlException..
i have load the driver successfully and want to execute the query ...but every time i found Exception how can i get rid of this problem.....

my code is as follows:

```
if(e.getSource()==b1)
    {
        if(t1.getText().equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"provide username to login");
            t1.requestFocus();
        }
        else if(t2.getText().equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"provide password to login");
            t2.requestFocus();
        }
        else 
        {
            String tablename=null;
            if(rb==1)
            {tablename="Admin";}
            else if(rb==2)
            {tablename="Clerks";}
            else if(rb==3)
            {tablename="members";}
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:librarysystem","","");
                    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from "+tablename+" where username=? and password=?");
                    ps.setString(1,t1.getText());
                    ps.setString(2,t2.getText());
                    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        //System.out.println(res);
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Registered user successful");
                        l=new library();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"wrong details entered");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception sql)
                {

                    t1.setText ("");
                    t2.setText ("");
                    t1.requestFocus ();
                    System.out.println(sql);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Incorrect excep Information Provided.");
                }
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==jrb1)
    {
        rb=1;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==jrb2)
    {
        rb=2;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==jrb3)
    {
        rb=3;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==b2)
    {
        f.setVisible(false);
        f.dispose();
        System.exit(152);
    }
```

this always shows : SQLException[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

plz help me..fnds

Comment: `Jdbc:Odbc` should be replaced with `jdbc:odbc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be caused by a zero length string as your sql login:

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:librarysystem","sa","sa_password");